How to sum up durations in Google Sheets for rows that meet criteria
I'm tracking time assigned to several different school theatre productions on a master calendar, where each row has the date, production name (Column F), start time, end time, and calculated duration (Column K). All of that is working. What I need to be able to do is calculate the total duration for each production. Right now I can filter the sheet using a production name in Column F, which causes data for the other productions to be hidden and leaves me with a nice stack of durations for that show alone. However, when I try to sum these up, it adds together all the values in the column, including those that are hidden by way of the filtering process.
Here is a link to a copy of the spreadsheet.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Assuming the duration is in Column_D
(header in D1 and data in the range D2:D)
=sumif(map(D2:D,lambda(Σ,subtotal(103,Σ))),1,D2:D)

